# Bringing more than one variable in the array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

im using a auto-complete (php,ajax) available online, but since im not familiar whit PDO hope for some help in what im doing wrong.

Basically i have a input field where the user can search by postcode or town name, but i need that in the label name shows always the name of the town, but the array brought by the $results variables is always of one column data.

Here is my Code:

auto-complete.php:

```
function serachForKeyword($keyword) {

    $db = getDbConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT  postcode, town FROM `uk_postcodes` WHERE postcode LIKE ? ORDER BY town");

    $keyword = $keyword . '%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    if ($isQueryOk) {
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    } else {

      trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $db = null; 

    return $results;
}
```

autocomplete.js:

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 2;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
        var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
        if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {

            $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
            .done(function( data ) {
                $('#results').html('');
                var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(results);
                $(results).each(function(key, value) {
                    $('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
                })

                $('.item').click(function() {
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    $('#keyword').val(text);
                })

            });
        } else {
            $('#results').html('');
        }
    });

    $("#keyword").blur(function(){
            $("#results").fadeOut(500);
        })
        .focus(function() {     
            $("#results").show();
        });

});
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(results)`? also if you do a `print_r($results)` before the `return` in the php function, what do you get?

Comment: @AlexAndrei in the console log i get a array of the postcodes

Comment: yes, share the array with us please :)